# What is the chunk-vendors.js file and how is it created? (Webpack)

Tags: webpack, vue-cli-3

I had a quick question regarding the `chunk-vendors.js` file that gets created during the build process for a Vue Js application.

What is it?
How is it created?

The reason I'm asking is to better understand how certain things end up in it. I'm finding it actually has some stuff I don't want.

Answer (score 26):

The `chunk-vendors.js`, as its name says, is a bundle for all the modules that are not your own, but from other parties. They are called *third-party* modules, or *vendor* modules.

Oftentimes, it means (only and) all the modules coming from the `/node_modules` directory of your project.

In webpack 3, you had to do it on your own, and you had to do a bit of boilerplate to have at least 2 chunks: one for your own code, and one for the modules from the `/node_modules` directory.

In webpack 4, it is quite simple: you use [`optimization.splitChunks`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/) with the default `options`:

```
    module.exports = {
      //...
      optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
          chunks: 'async',
          minSize: 30000,
          maxSize: 0,
          minChunks: 1,
          maxAsyncRequests: 5,
          maxInitialRequests: 3,
          automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
          name: true,
          cacheGroups: {
            vendors: {
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/, // this is what you are looking for
              priority: -10
            },
            default: {
              minChunks: 2,
              priority: -20,
              reuseExistingChunk: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

@vue/cli 3 using webpack 4, it uses the defaults if you don't [change the webpack configuration](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html).

Comment: If I have a large dependency that is only used by admin, is it possible to putt it in a separate chunk? It seems like all dependencies get bundled into `chunk-vendors.js` and sent to all users.

Comment: I don't really get it. I have a nearly-empty skeleton project created with `vue cli` that comes with 117kb of JS inside `chunk-vendors.js`! Why so large? I don't think I've added anything else. Maybe that's just the raw size of Webpack's loader and Vue JS itself?

Comment: Vue 2 or Vue 3? With or without Vuex? With or without Vue-router?...